# Live sound at professional hockey games

Tags: microphone, live-sound, sport

Was wondering what kind of mics are used the get the sound of the hits, skates, sticks etc. for the live broadcasts of pro hockey games. Like a couple dynamic or condenser mics setup around the rink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the AAC during Stars games they use a series of MKH 60s (including one mounted in the center scoreboard) and an array of crown PZM mics located on the glass every couple of panels.

Comment: Senators use the same basic setup at ScotiaBank Place...

Answer (score 3):

NHL standard is 10 Crown PLL160 mics around the rink.   blue lines on both sides, red lines on both sides, and behind each goal.   Some A1's spec two mics mounted a pane or two apart behind the goal for a bit of a stereo image.    Add to that an x-y pair of short shotguns for crowd mounted up high in the arena and that's how most NHL broadcasts are mic'd